# How to show errors for relations on the main Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I want to include errors from a rather deep assocation in a parent:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product, polymorphic: true
end

class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :line_item, as: :product, autosave: true

   validates :domain, presence: true
end
```

Used as:

```
product = Site.new(domain: nil)
order = Order.new
order.line_items << LineItem.new(product: product)
order.valid? #=> false
product.valid? #=> false
product.errors? #=> { 'domain' => 'cannot be blank' }
```

Is there some rails way, or association-parameter to make the errors
bubble up so that I get:

```
order.errors  #=> { 'domain' => 'cannot be blank' }
```

In other words, that the Order, the top of the association,
transparently proxies the validation errors from its children?

I am aware of using simple before_validation hooks, like so:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_validation :add_errors_from_line_items

   private
   def add_errors_from_line_items
     self.line_items.each do |line_item|
       line_item.product.errors.each do |field, message|
         errors.add(field, message)
       end unless line_item.product.valid?
     end
   end
end
```

end

But I am wondering if there is not some ActiveRecord feature that I am overlooking.

Comment: Do you use the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your forms? How do you populate & send data to your models?

Comment: We have this type of setup working, but we use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` - I can give you the code if you want

Comment: This is an API-only app, so no forms. But `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, AFAIK requires attributes in a nested format and will return the errors in that way too. What I want, is to have "Order" be a more transparent "proxy" for setting up its associations; so that the consumer of Order does not need to know about Site and such. My code actually builds the LineItems inside Order based on businesslogic.

Comment: Hmmmm you'll be looking at a deeper level integration here -- perhaps using [ActiveRecord Association Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions)?